# How to get the smallest non-zero float64?

Tags: go

The math library doesn't seem to have a Min function for float64. How would I get the smallest non-zero float64?

Comment: `SmallestNonzeroFloat64`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as @oliver-charlesworth says:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%.12G", math.SmallestNonzeroFloat64)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/kRuIhalODGa

Output:

```
4.94065645841E-324
```